# Detect When Mouse Enters Specific Area of Document (Not a Div Element)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how [Medium](https://uxplanet.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-creating-a-mobile-application-8e2b265580d9#.gz177pyof) made their bottom action / menu bar slide up when your mouse enters the bottom of the document. The slide up effect is not triggered by moving the mouse over the invisible div (it slides up & down via transform translateY).

Besides, the menu bar is only 44px in height, but its is-visible class gets triggered way before your mouse is near it — but by what? When using Inspect Element, I can't see any hidden divs that could be triggering it..

I've searched for countless of ways, e.g. "show element when mouse enters specific part of document" but all search results involve when the mouse enters or moves over a div element, which is not the solution I'm looking for.

Obviously, you can solve this problem by putting the slide up menu inside a hidden container like I've done here, and then you get the desired result:

```js
(function() {

  var actionBar = document.querySelector('.action-bar');
  var actionBarWrapper = document.querySelector('.action-bar-detection');

  function showDiv() {
    actionBar.classList.add('js-is-visible')
  }

  function hideDiv() {
    actionBar.classList.remove('js-is-visible')
  }

  actionBarWrapper.onmouseover = showDiv;
  actionBarWrapper.onmouseout = hideDiv;

})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.action-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #252321;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 99;
}

.action-bar-detection {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.js-is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <p>When mouse enters the hidden action bar element, slides up.</p>
    <p>But it's only happening because the action-bar is inside an invisible detection layer class (action-bar-detection) with a height of 150px.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="action-bar-detection">
    <div class="action-bar">

      Bottom Menu
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**However, this doesn't seem to be what Medium have done, and if this can be done without adding more HTML & CSS, I want to learn how! :-)**

I think I'm not phrasing the problem correctly, since I can't find any solutions even remotely close (I've searched A LOT).

Any advice? What should I read up on? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by listening to the `mousemove` event on the document, you will want to invest effort into making this performant as it will be triggered frequently. The most common way to regulate events like this is through [throttling](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Once you are hooked into the mousemove event you will need to get the Y coordinate of the cursor and compare that to the height of the window, if it is within a threshold then you can reveal your panel, once it moves out you can proceed to hide it again.

Here is an example showing a basic implementation [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jpLuo2c/)

```js
// Using underscore for the throttle function though you can implement your own if you wish
document.addEventListener('mousemove', _.throttle(mouseMoveEventAction, 200));

function mouseMoveEventAction(e) {
 doPanelStuff(isInsideThreshold(e.clientY));
}

function doPanelStuff(isActive) {
 var panelElement = document.querySelector('.panel');
  if (isActive) {
   panelElement.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
   panelElement.style.removeProperty('background');
  }
}

function isInsideThreshold(cursorY) {
 var threshold = 200;
 var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  return cursorY > (clientHeight - threshold);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container, .content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't even thought about the throttling issue!

Answer (score 3):

Get height of viewport, track `onmousemove`, and compare `clientY` from the mouse event to the viewport height:

```js
(function() {

  var actionBar = document.querySelector('.action-bar');
  var viewHeight = window.innerHeight - 150;

  function toggleDiv(e) {
    if (e.clientY >= viewHeight) {
      actionBar.classList.add('js-is-visible');
    } else {
      actionBar.classList.remove('js-is-visible');
    }
  }

  window.onmousemove = toggleDiv;

})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
.action-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #252321;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 99;
}
.action-bar-detection {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.js-is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>When mouse comes within 150px of the bottom part of the screen, the bar slides up.</p>
  <p>When the mouse leaves this defined area of the screen, the bar slides down.</p>
</div>
<div class="action-bar-detection">
  <div class="action-bar">
    Bottom Menu
  </div>
</div>
```