# How can I detect whether the mouse is in a certain part of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, pts

So I'm trying to change the value of a variable based on the Y coordinate of the pointer, and I'm not sure how I would do this.  I tried this:

```
 var righttext = mousemove.clientY;
 switch(righttext){
     case //not sure what to put here
     }
```

but I wasn't sure what to put in the case.  What I want to do is have something like this example: `case "top 20% of screen"`.  How would I figure out what the coordinates of the screen are, and then figure out how to use that in a switch statement?

The parts that I want to affect the value are just fifths of the screen divided horizontally.

EDIT:

So I was linked to another post, and found a similar answer to what I was looking for.  I changed the code to look like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', _.throttle(mouseMoveEventAction, 200));

function mouseMoveEventAction(e) {
 changetext(isInsideThreshold(e.clientY));
}
var rpaneltext = "";

function changetext(isActive) {
  if (isActive) {
      rpaneltext = "awareness";
  } else {
      rpaneltext = "";
  }
}

function isInsideThreshold(cursorY) {
 var threshold = .2;
 var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  return cursorY > (clientHeight - threshold);
}
```

But it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Project [here](https://codepen.io/seppemane/pen/NLOzaO):  The part that will be affected by `righttext` is `document.querySelector(".r2").textContent = righttext`

Comment: when you say top 20%, do you mean of the whole screen including if it's scrollable, or just the immediate viewport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect When Mouse Enters Specific Area of Document (Not a Div Element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263871/detect-when-mouse-enters-specific-area-of-document-not-a-div-element)

Comment: `switch` is not suitable for the task, `case` will do strict equality comparison with the given value, you can't go through the whole screen pixel by pixel.

Comment: @zfrisch it's going to be a non-scrollable directory page, so just the immediate viewport.

Comment: Different parts require different approaches. What parts (shape, value, etc.)  are we talking about? Define a few, and people will suggest some solutions. Then you can apply the solution to your specific needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`. They return the viewport dimensions.

You may have better luck with if-else logic like this.

```
if (event.clientY < window.innerHeight / 2) {
    // it's in the upper half
} else {
    // it's in the lower half
}
```